# Reading file character by character to array

Tags: lua

I was searching for long time, how to read whole file into character array. My current code:

```
function readWholeFile(fn)
  if(fn==nil) then 
    return nil 
  end
  local file = io.open(fn, "r")
  return file:read("*a")
end
```

I want to this function return

```
{'s', 'o', 'm', 'e', 't', 'e', 'x', 't'}
```

instead of

```
"Sometext"
```

So how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the whole file as you did, and split the content string into characters. This could be done easily with the `string` library. e.g:

```
for c in content:gmatch(".") do
```

---

Another possible solution:

[`file:read`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:read) supports several formats, `file:read("*a")` is the way to read the whole file. Instead, use `file:read(1)` to read one character each time, e.g:

```
repeat
  local c = file:read(1)
  print(c)
until c == nil
```

Comment: In newer Lua version (5.2+) `io.lines()` and `file:lines()` support the same formats as `file:read()`, so `for c in file:lines( 1 ) do ... end` should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

gmatch works with patterns, it looks a bit overkill IMHO, all you need is string.sub()

```
local text = readWholeFile("filename")
local t = {}
for i=1, #text do t[#t + 1] = text:sub(i,1) end
```